# su user executes command as root

Tags: linux, bash

**Short Background:**

when running a script  that uses `notify-send "title" "message"`, it is expected to show a notification, but `sudo ./script` does not show notification

After reading up and visiting many a page, I found that running this part (notify-send part) of my script could still notify the user.

**Problem:**

Thus testing this su command:

```
su normal-user -c "echo $USER"
root
```

Why is this not returning `normal-user`

Answer (score 4):

The $USER variable is expanded at the time you enter the command not after the su as run.  `su normal-user -c 'echo $USER'` will yield the expected results.  The single quotes mean that $USER won't be expanded until after the su.